# Printing the top 10% used words in a text

Tags: java, arrays, printing, count

I have an assignment which I am working on. I have made two arrays, one who saves every unique word, and one who counts how many times every unique word is used.
Now I need to find the highest valued array, meaning the most used word, and then print every word that falls into the category:top ten used words from there. I have made one attempt but it fails on the finding the highest value-part. (And if someone could give me a tip on how to make the program read the text and save the words without commas, slashes etc, please do)

> I am not allowed to use HashMaps, sorry about that. Forgot to mention.

the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Oblig3B{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    OrdAnalyse oa = new OrdAnalyse();
    String filArgs=args[0];
    oa.analyseMetode(filArgs);
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse{
    void analyseMetode(String filArgs){

    //Begynner med aa opprette alle variabler som trengs, disse deklareres rett under. De ligger her oppe bare for at jeg skal ha oversikten over de.
    Scanner input, innfil;
    String[] ord;
    int[] antall;
    int antUnikeOrd, antOrd;
    PrintWriter utfil;
    boolean sjekk;

    //Deklarerer alle bortsett fra de som har med fil aa gjore, disse deklareres inne i en try-catch-loop (printwriter utfil og scanner innfil).
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ord=new String[5000];
    antall=new int[5000];
    antUnikeOrd=0;
    antOrd=0;
    sjekk=true;

    try{
        innfil=new Scanner(new File(filArgs));
        //Naa sjekker programmet om ordet som blir lest med Scanner-metoden er lest for. Er det slik, saa oeker den antallet i samme index i antall-arrayen med 1, den boolske verdien sjekk blir true, og neste if-lokke vil ikke kjore, for loopen er ferdig og neste ord leses.
        //Here it reads the file, word by word.
        while(innfil.hasNext()){
        String ordLest=innfil.next().toLowerCase(); 
        sjekk=false;
            for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
            if(ordLest.equals(ord[i])){
            antall[i]+=1;
            sjekk=true;
            }
        }
        if(!sjekk){
            //Her vil lokken oke telleren antUnikeOrd med en for hvert unike ord som leses, og denne er alltid en
            ord[antUnikeOrd]=ordLest;
            antall[antUnikeOrd]++;
            antUnikeOrd++;
        }

        antOrd++;
        }
        innfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try{
        utfil=new PrintWriter(new File("Oppsummering.txt"));

        utfil.println("Antall ord lest: " +antOrd+ " og antall unike ord: "+antUnikeOrd+"      "+ ord.length);

        finnOrd(antall, ord, utfil);

        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        utfil.println(ord[i]+("  ")+antall[i]);
        }

        utfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

//This is the method where I will find the top ten percent most used words. 

    void finnOrd(int[] antall, String[] ord, PrintWriter utfil){
    int teller=1000;
    for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>teller){
        teller=antall[i];
        }
        //Naa er teller lik den hoyeste verdien i antall-arrayen.
        double tiprosent=teller*0.90;
        System.out.println(tiprosent + "   " + teller);
        for(i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>tiprosent){
            utfil.println("Vanlige ord: "+ord[i]+"\t("+antall[i]+" forekomster)");
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a LinkedHashMap and then sort it using a custom comparator?

Answer (score 0):

as @Gustavo said in his comment, put them in a hash like `MyHash<string, int>,` then order `MyHash` by `Value`

Comment: Forgot to add that: not allowed to use hashmaps

Answer (score 0):

antall[antUnikeOrd]++;
antUnikeOrd++;

Can you explain to me what those are doing? And also what antall[i]+=1;
above it is doing? It sounds to me like you might be duplicating the work, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding some of the language, so it's hard to say for sure.

However, if that is duplicating it, it wouldn't actually be important, because it's doubling everything equally!

I see you in your finnOrd method, you're starting with int teller=1000;

Is teller arbitrary, or do you know for *certain* that there will be exactly 10000 individual words? I know your array is that length, but you're not sure if every element will be filled (unless that's part of the instructions specifically). If you don't know for certain, you've got a much better metric for figuring out what 10% is - antUnikeOrd is counting up the unique words, so 10% of the number of unique words will properly give you what you need there.

Now there's a couple of ways of actually finding the words - you can use a Hash, like has been suggested, but my thinking is maybe you're not allowed to.

You only want to go through the result list once, so you could maybe create an array[10] that would store the highest rated last ten words.

You could also take this time to learn about sorting, and look into what it takes to sort an array - at which point you just pull out the first ten things.

You could go the really inefficient way and go through the array ten times, pulling out the top word each time and setting it's count to zero. This one's no good as a real option, but I threw it out there so you could start thinking about different ways you could try to solve this.

Comment: The antall[i]+=1 adds one to the antall-array which stores how many of each unique word is registered in the file. the other two will register a word in the array at  the index where the value for the current maximum counted unique words is at if that word is not currently existing in the array, and antall[antUnikeOrd]++ is adding one value to the antall-array at the same index, to start counting every occurrence of that word. 
No, it was just to set the teller to something. I tried to use it as a value to get the for-loop below started.